# Regular Expression Validator for Letters and Numbers only

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

What is the Regular Expression Validator for only Letters and Numbers in asp.net?

I need to enter only 0-9,a-z and A-Z. I don't want to allow any special characters single or double quotes etc. I am using asp.net 3.5 framework.

I tried `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` and `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`. They are not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the following.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

go to this [example](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1014) and also [alphanumerics](http://forums.asp.net/t/1097288.aspx/1) for more

then try this

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

If length restriction is necessary use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,50}$
```

This will match alphanumeric strings of 0 to 50 chars.

Comment: <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
       ControlToValidate="txt_consumer_no" ErrorMessage="Enter Only Numeric and characters" 
               ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: What if I want to had the slash / and - ? Is it ^[a-zA-Z0-9 - \\/]*$ ?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this....

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

see more [info at here](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1014)

Comment: And specifically for a regex validator, you don't even need the "^" en "$" (although they do no harm)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a regular expression as follows,

```
Regex myRegularExpression = new Regex(" \b^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$\b");
```

be sure to include `System.Text.RegularExpression`

and then use the `Regex` to match it with your user-control as follows,

eg : if your user-control is a textbox

```
myRegularExpression.isMatch(myTextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear English speaking people. With all due respect. A-Z are not the only letters in the world. Please use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9]` if you support other languages in your apps

Comment: But `\w` includes `_` as well ;-)